# Abstracting Hspec tests

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, hspec

I am going through "Haskell programming from first principles" and I found myself writing code in the following fashion over and over:

```
type IntToInt = Fun Int Int
type TypeIdentity = ConcreteFunctorType Int -> Bool
type TypeComposition = ConcreteFunctorType Int -> IntToInt -> IntToInt -> Bool

checkSomething :: IO ()
checkSomething = hspec $ do
        describe "Some functor" $ do
            it "identity property" $ do
                property $ (functorIdentity :: TypeIdentity)
            it "composition property" $ do
                property $ (functorComposition :: TypeComposition)
```

I tried abstracting this but at my level I am not able to figure out a way to make it work

what I would have liked to accomplish was something like this

```
checkFunctor :: (Functor f) => String -> f a -> IO ()
checkFunctor description f = hspec $ do
        describe description $ do
            it "identity property" $ do
                property $ (functorIdentity :: f a -> TypeIdentity)
            it "composition property" $ do
                property $ ( functorComposition :: f a -> TypeComposition)
```

EDIT:
After Sapanoia's answer I tried as follows

```
type TypeIdentity = Bool
type TypeComposition = Fun Int Int -> Fun Int Int -> Bool


checkFunctor :: forall f a. (Functor f) => String -> f a -> IO ()
checkFunctor description f = hspec $ do
    describe description $ do
        it "identity property" $ do
            property $ (functorIdentity :: f a -> TypeIdentity)
        it "composition property" $ do
            property $ (functorCompose' :: f a -> TypeComposition)
```

but I get the following error

```
FunctorCheck.hs:22:25: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Int’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      checkFunctor :: forall (f :: * -> *) a.
                      Functor f =>
                      String -> f a -> IO ()
    at FunctorCheck.hs:16:26
  Expected type: f a -> TypeComposition
    Actual type: f Int -> Fun Int Int -> Fun Int Int -> Bool
```

It then becomes quite complicated for me to define the types to generate the arbitrary values and functions.

Is there a way I can bind the type of checkFunctor to a specific type like  the following?

```
checkFuntor :: checkFunctor :: forall f Int. (Functor f) => String -> f a -> IO ()
```

of course I tried this and it gives me a parse error, I assume it's just me not using 'forall' correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can do this using `ScopedTypeVariables`, and it can be made even nicer by using GHC 8’s `TypeApplications` along with `AllowAmbiguousTypes`.

Comment: `forall` is used to introduce a new type *variable*. *Concrete* types such as `Int` need not be introduced, just insert them instead of a *type variable*. Your example then becomes: `checkFunctor :: forall f. (Functor f) => String -> f Int -> IO ()`. In the body of `checkFunctor` you need accordingly: `functorIdentity :: f Int -> TypeIdentity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not add an error message, I assume the problem is a type error where `(functorIdentity :: f a -> TypeIdentity)` is defined. The problem is that the `f` introduced here is new and different from the `f` in the top-level signature. To remedy this, enable the following extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

And change the signature of `checkFunctor` to:

```
checkFunctor :: forall f a. (Functor f) => String -> f a -> IO ()
```

`forall` introduces new *type variables*. Without *ScopedTypeVariables* and an explicit `forall` it is always present implicitly, and `(functorIdentity :: f a -> TypeIdentity)` becomes `(functorIdentity :: forall f a. f a -> TypeIdentity)`. However, you do *not* want a forall here, because you want the type variables `f` and `a` to be the same as the top-level ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I edited the question after I tried this, although without success